# WCF change attribute nillable to nil

Tags: wcf

I developed a WS and the WSDL in visual studio, using c#, the WSDL contains nillable="true", but the client does not support, how can I change nillable="true" to xsi:nil="true".

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the XSD schema nillable attaribute with the XSD schema-instance nil attribute. They are linked, but not equivalent.

Please see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils for clarity.

The XSD schema nillable attribute is a decorator on the element to allow an explicit null value to be assigned to the element in conforming XML documents.

The XSD schema instance nil attribute is the way to define an explicit null value in a XML document.

> the WSDL contains nillable="true", but the client does not support

You need to explain exactly what you mean by this. Is the client unable to consume the WSDL from your service? What is the error they are getting?